# Pandoc Latex: Overflow in Longtable

Tags: longtable, urls, pandoc

I use pandoc with some custom LaTeX template to generate a PDF Table. Hence, I cannot easily influence how Pandoc generates the table code, but instead I can change the configuration in the Latex document.

When I use Pandoc to have a table with long links, the column *count* is overflowing. How can I prevent this?

### Markdown for Pandoc

```
#### Adblock Findings

The Adblock findings summarise requests that would have been detected and blocked by the Adblock list [easyprivacy.txt](https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt) from <https://easylist.to/>.

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sample                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          count
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
  <http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1

  <http://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j68&a=1570329088&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eba.europa.eu%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Home%20-%20European%20Banking%20Authority&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1356x694&je=0&_u=IEBAAEAB~&jid=799733851&gjid=1328499242&cid=1310586057.1530548844&tid=UA-41571870-1&_gid=670816676.1530548844&_r=1&z=1576148449>                                                                                                                                                               2
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### LaTeX (simplified)

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,a4paper,parskip=true,titlepage=true]{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}
  \usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
\usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
  \setromanfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} % url is loaded by hyperref
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % color is loaded by hyperref
\usepackage[unicode=true,draft]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle={},
  pdfsubject={},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=darkblue,
  citecolor=Red,
  urlcolor=darkblue,
  breaklinks=true,
  pdfpagemode=UseNone,
  pageanchor=true,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
}

\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,main=british]{babel}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\fi

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{adblock-findings}{%
\paragraph{Adblock Findings}\label{adblock-findings}}

The Adblock findings summarise requests that would have been detected and blocked by the Adblock list \href{https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt}{easyprivacy.txt} from \url{https://easylist.to/}.

\mbox{}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.90\columnwidth}\raggedright
sample\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.04\columnwidth}\raggedright
count\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.90\columnwidth}\raggedright
\url{http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.04\columnwidth}\raggedright
1\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.90\columnwidth}\raggedright
\url{http://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1\&_v=j68\&a=1570329088\&t=pageview\&_s=1\&dl=http\%3A\%2F\%2Fwww.eba.europa.eu\%2F\&ul=en-us\&de=UTF-8\&dt=Home\%20-\%20European\%20Banking\%20Authority\&sd=24-bit\&sr=1366x768\&vp=1356x694\&je=0\&_u=IEBAAEAB~\&jid=799733851\&gjid=1328499242\&cid=1310586057.1530548844\&tid=UA-41571870-1\&_gid=670816676.1530548844\&_r=1\&z=1576148449}\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.04\columnwidth}\raggedright
2\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}




\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: PDF Screenhot of MWE]